# Extending abstract base class with class template

Tags: c++

How can I extend an abstract base class using templates for the extensions when I also wish to conditionally compile the overrides for the pure virtual functions?

Example: Given the base class

```
class AbstractBase {
public:
  virtual void func() = 0;
};
```

I thought of extending with something like

```
enum class Opts{FOO, BAR};

template<Opts opt>
class Derived : public AbstractBase {
public:

  template<Opts op = opt>
  typename std::enable_if<op == Opts::FOO, void>::type func() {
    std::cout << "Foo" << "\n";
  }

  template<Opts op = opt>
  typename std::enable_if<op == Opts::BAR, void>::type func() {
    std::cout << "BAR" << "\n";
  }

};
```

My idea is that when one of the func get to compile in the extended class, then everything's good. However, I can't get it to work.

```
Derived<Opts::FOO> obj;
```

Will not compile because the derived class is is still abstract. I'm using templates because I want the compiler to pick only one member function to compile.

Thanks.

Comment: Function templates aren't virtual, so they can't override anything.

Comment: Sounds like you really want 2 different derived classes

Comment: Have a look at the famous [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

Just specialize the class template for each to-be-treated-specially enum value, e.g.,

```
enum class Opts{foo, bar};

template<Opts opt>
class Derived;

template<>
class Derived<Opts::foo>
    : public AbstractBase
{
public:
    void func() override
    {
        std::cout << "Foo" << "\n";
    }
};

template<>
class Derived<Opts::bar>
    : public AbstractBase
{
public:
    void func() override
    {
        std::cout << "bar" << "\n";
    }
};
```

Where you want some general common stuff that's not in `AbstractBase`, you can either inherit it in, or add it in via CRTP in a most derived class.

Disclaimer: off the cuff code, not compiled.

Answer (score 1):

You may specialize the function instead:

```
#include <iostream>

class AbstractBase
{
    public:
    // You should have a virtual destructor:
    virtual ~AbstractBase() {}
    virtual void func() = 0;
};

enum class Opts
{
    FOO, BAR
};

template<Opts opt>
class Derived: public AbstractBase
{
    public:
    void func() override;
};

template<>
void Derived<Opts::FOO>::func()
{
    std::cout << "Foo" << "\n";
}

template<>
void Derived<Opts::BAR>::func()
{
    std::cout << "BAR" << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    Derived<Opts::FOO> foo;
    AbstractBase& bfoo = foo;
    bfoo.func();
    Derived<Opts::BAR> bar;
    AbstractBase& bbar = bar;
    bbar.func();
}
```

However, I consider mixing dynamic polymorphism (virtual) and static polymorphism (templates) a bad design (there might be exemptions).

Comment: I see. I have a small collection of "helper" classes. They're all tiny and they all override only one virtual member function of the base class. I thought of not keeping them all and do something with templates instead. It seems to me that keeping it as it is may be not so bad after all.